# Qt Creator display in application output: NVD3DREL: GR-805 : DX9 Overlay is DISABLED

Tags: c++, qt, directx, qt-creator, nvidia

As I am working with my project, I noticed that when I run my app, inside the *Application Output* area I can see message:

```
NVD3DREL:  GR-805 : DX9 Overlay is DISABLED
NVD3DREL:  GR-805 : DX9 Overlay is DISABLED
NVD3DREL:  GR-805 : DX9 Overlay is DISABLED
```

I have no idea what it means, but to be honest it has no impact on my app, but I don't like to see any kind of unnecessary messages. I've tried to google it, but found no similar issues. What might be a reason? I wasn't doing any changes in my code but this message appeared out of nowhere. Lately I installed CUDA SDK on my PC for another project and that's the only connection I can think of with DirectX. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This issue still happens with Qt 5.15.2 and NVIDIA driver 511.23 release date 01/14/2022.

Comment: 512.92 still has it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is a problem in the Nvidia Driver 496.13. I had the same problem, and reverting to an older version fixed it

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I can also confirm this is the Nvidia driver version: 496.13 issue. I have switched back to driver version: 472.12 for now. Also, I have contacted the support team, they suggested to report it here: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/471331/geforce-49613-grd-feedback-thread-released-101221/

Also, I have reported this issue on the Nvidia developer forum: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvd3drel-gr-805-dx9-overlay-is-disabled/196940

Comment: Version 497.09 (released 01-Dec-21) still has it...

Comment: Version 497.29 (released 2021.12.20) still has it...